# Cross-references - how to control 'levels'?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm sure this must have been asked and answered many times, but I just can't seem to think of the right words for my search. I want to reference the following diagram, which is labeled '3.16.1', but I only get '3.16' in the reference. How can I control the number of 'levels'?

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Comment: Quite likely you have `\label` before `\caption`.

Comment: @egreg Is that really all? I'll try it and post an example, if it doesn't fix my issue. (thx)

Comment: @egreg You were right! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it so you can harvest some points :-)